# Split bytes into at least 3 different lengths then save them to array/variable

Tags: arrays, linux, math, byte

As a prelude, the split tool on Linux can do it:

```
$ du -b file.mp4
9840497 file.mp4
$ split -e --number=3 --verbose file.mp4 && du -b xa*
3280165 xaa
3280165 xab
3280167 xac
```

But the split tool makes the 1st part, `xaa`, the same size as the 2nd part, `xab`. And the following method can only show one part:

```
$ parts=$((9840497 / 3))
$ echo -n "$parts"
3280165
```

So now, how do I divide the `9840497` bytes into 3 unequal different lengths and then store all of them sequentially into an array / variable, `of course without having to divide them using the split tool` ?.

Comment: `echo "scale=4;9840497 / 3" | bc` returns `3280165.6666` . Good luck.

Comment: But its not clear why you want 3 unequal parts. Assuming that the `...167` portion is fixed, you have to find something else that sums to `10`, so `...6` and `...4`? `7,3;8,2;9;1;X,0` ? And generally such toy problems are a placeholder for a desired general tool, where the "full" number can be split into any N segments. (Is that true for you?) .... *"how do I divide the 9840497 bytes into 3 unequal different lengths...*" . It seems like you want the `dd` command and it `offset` options. ... *"v into an array / variable,"*, Storing binary data in shell variables is highly impractical. ...

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're not talking about shell variables? `python` has all sorts of tools for dealing with all types of data. Maybe that is what you want. But until you give readers a use-case we're just left to guess and ask you "Is it bigger than a breadbox, .... smaller than a house' questions (-;. Good luck!

Comment: (... edit to above ... why do you want 3 unequal parts, ... why isn't 5 5 7 good enough?). Good luck.

Comment: What is `.6666` of a byte?